# Automount CIFS share permission issue

Tags: automount, cifs

Having issues setting Write access when mounting a CIFS mount. Ubuntu Server/Client. Details are in the paste.  I tried to provide as much info that I could think, but please let me know if you need more info:

https://pastebin.com/1JSdiEmN
*let me know if I shouldn't use pastebin and just post the code here

What am I missing? Did I mess up the smb.conf masks/modes? I've been searching forums and adding/removing arguments trying to get it to work -- no luck.
I've tried both lines in the CLIENT /etc/fstab

(i created the test files from the console of the SERVER)

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Are you the user `deluge`? If you're only in the group `deluge` you should try `file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775`.

Comment: Apologies this wasn't clear:  clientUser is my user account on the CLIENT machine.  On CLIENT, I'm running the Deluge service that runs as user "deluge" and needs read/write access to that /mnt/tmp location.

Comment: I edited /etc/fstab with the following: //SERVER/tmp /mnt/tmp cifs credentials=/home/clientUser/.smbcred,uid=deluge,gid=deluge,vers=3.0,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,iocharset=utf8 0 0

And it worked!  Am I good to go with this?  Any redundancy I can get rid of?  Thank you so much @AnthonyKelly

Answer (score 0):

Per @AnthonyKelly's response, adding the file_mode arguments fixed my issue.  End /etc/fstab file:

```
//SERVER/tmp /mnt/tmp cifs credentials=/home/clientUser/.smbcred,uid=deluge,gid=deluge,vers=3.0,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Thanks again, Andrew.